# Is there Ubuntu Server for 32bit systems?

Tags: server, 32-bit

Please help! I have 3 desktops and 1 laptop and bring the laptop everywhere and keep the 3 desktops at home and they all have Ubuntu on them and I would like to access media and any kind of files I have on all of them through or with my laptop when I'm traveling! All 3 desktops and 1 laptop are all 32 bit systems! So how can I install and run Ubuntu Server on 32 bit systems?

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit server can be download via Torrent: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso.torrent

Or can be downloaded directly: http://de.releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso

Any other ways of doing it are mentioned in the **Alternative Downloads** in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

I know it is tough to find the 32-bit version but that is because it is becoming less a less recommended (and used). With the amount of default RAM some laptops already have and all current CPU supporting 64-bit, 32-bit is becoming less of a server architecture (and soon less of a desktop one).